# Get space on top of section when scrolling using Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navigationbar

I think that this is a really simple question but I can´t get a solution by myself.

I have a fixed navigation bar in Bootstrap 3 and when I click in one of the nav items it scrolls down to the section with the proper ID. However, it goes all the way until the very beginning of the text. I would like to give it a little bit of space (padding) on top of the text, so i tis easier to read.

This is an example of what I am saying.

[image]

However, I would like it to scroll down until the start of the section, including the padding space I have. Like this:

[image]

So basically if I could set the menu to navigate to around 20 or 30px on top of the section that would be perfect, because I don´t want to add more padding or margins since that would put too much white space in the site when you are manually scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the section with the proper ID has `margin-top: x`, change it on `padding-top: x`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I use a jQuery plugin to handle this offsetting of position. Check out [Animated Scroll](https://github.com/ramswaroop/animatescroll.js) on github.

I don't have all the code to hand, but I use this to kick it off:

```
    $('.btn--scroll-down').click(function () { 
      $(this).parents('.jsScrollPoint').next('.jsScrollPoint').animatescroll();
    });
```

If you read the docs, you'll notice an option for padding - that's your offset.